# Service Fabric .Net Framework 4.5.1 and 4.6

Tags: azure-service-fabric

After changing the target framework from 4.5.1 to 4.6 the service in Auzure Fail, the local deployment is working.

Do I need to add .Net 4.6 support ? - I'm unable to find where I can see the frameworks available in my cluster in azure.

Thank you

> ApplicationName                 :
>   fabric:/Lending20.Service.IdentityManagement  AggregatedHealthState
>   : Error  UnhealthyEvaluations            :
>                                      Unhealthy services: 100% (1/1), ServiceType='IdentityManagementServiceType',
>                                      MaxPercentUnhealthyServices=0%.
>
> Unhealthy service:
>   ServiceName='fabric:/Lending20.Service.IdentityManagement/Identity
>                                      ManagementService', AggregatedHealthState='Error'.
>
> Unhealthy partitions: 100% (1/1),
>   MaxPercentUnhealthyPartitionsPerService=0%.
>
> Unhealthy partition:
>   PartitionId='7c68b397-fda3-491d-9e17-921cd24217ca',
>                                      AggregatedHealthState='Error'.
>
> Error event: SourceId='System.FM', Property='State'.
>
> ServiceHealthStates             :
>                                      ServiceName           :
>                                      fabric:/Lending20.Service.IdentityManagement/IdentityManagementService
>                                      AggregatedHealthState : Error
>
> DeployedApplicationHealthStates :
>                                      ApplicationName       : fabric:/Lending20.Service.IdentityManagement
>                                      NodeName              : _lending1
>                                      AggregatedHealthState : Ok
>
> HealthEvents                    :
>                                      SourceId              : System.CM
>                                      Property              : State
>                                      HealthState           : Ok
>                                      SequenceNumber        : 3464
>                                      SentAt                : 11/21/2015 12:38:08 PM
>                                      ReceivedAt            : 11/21/2015 12:38:08 PM
>                                      TTL                   : Infinite
>                                      Description           : Application has been created.
>                                      RemoveWhenExpired     : False
>                                      IsExpired             : False
>                                      Transitions           : Warning->Ok = 11/21/2015 12:38:08 PM, LastError = 1/1/0001
>                                      12:00:00 AM

Answer (score 5, accepted):

.NET 4.6 is not yet available in the default Windows Server 2012 image used in Azure. At this point, your only option is to log into each VM and install it.

Answer (score 17):

You can use the following ARM template to install .NET 4.6.1. Note that it's dependent on this [script](https://www.azureserviceprofiler.com/content/downloads/InstallNetFx46.ps1) (used by Service Profiler). You also can replace it with any other PowerShell script.

The parameter is the base name of the node. So if you have VM0,.. VM5  in your cluster, you should set vmName = 'VM'. The `vmExtensionLoop` is set to 5 nodes; you can also change that of course.

If you use an ARM template to deploy your cluster, you can include this as part of it. Note it can slow down the deployment of the scale set, since it requires a restart.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "vmName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Virtual machine name."
      },
    }
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2015-05-01-preview",
      "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('vmName'),copyIndex(0), '/CustomScriptExtensionInstallNet461')]",
      "location": "[variables('location')]",
      "tags": {
        "displayName": "CustomScriptExtensionInstallNet461"
      },
      "properties": {
        "publisher": "Microsoft.Compute",
        "type": "CustomScriptExtension",
        "typeHandlerVersion": "1.4",
        "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
        "settings": {
          "fileUris": [ "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/aelij/7ea90dda4a187a482584/raw/a3e0f946d4a22b0af803edb503d0a30a263fba2c/InstallNetFx461.ps1" ],
          "commandToExecute": "powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File InstallNetFx461.ps1"
        }
      },
      "copy": {
        "name": "vmExtensionLoop",
        "count": 5
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the windows Server 2016 image to get .net 4.6.1. pre installed. vmImageSku:"2016-Datacenter" when provisoning the cluster.

Comment: Actually it's 4.6.2 now. Also see: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2007/03/14/mailbag-what-version-of-the-net-framework-is-included-in-what-version-of-the-os/.

Answer (score 0):

another option is use azure resource group template that includes a DSC extension to provision your VMs to have .net 46 installed.
Here is the snippet in my dsc powershell to deal with the installation of .net 461
    [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QSPI.png) or [gist](https://gist.github.com/zhangxd6/8bf7586c2037b2757d39) for more complete script

Comment: This is actually quite hard, since .NET 4.6.1 is not a seperate product, but a windows update. The default powershell version in Windows Server 2012 R2 is 4.0 and DSC in 4.0 does not support handling windows updates.

So in order to leverage DSC with windows updates, one should first install powershell 5.0, then use the Install-Module cmdlet to fetch the xWindowsUpdate DSC custom resource, before applying the .NET 4.6.1 windows update.

Quite hard compared to the Powershell custom script extension supplied by Eli.

Answer (score 0):

Until 4.6 is supported by Azure natively, I'd use a custom VM image with .NET 4.6 preinstalled. See [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-upload-image/) for details on how to create and use one.

Answer (score 0):

Now .NET 4.6 and above is available in the Release of SDK 2.5.216 and Runtime 5.5.216

For more details please see: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-azure-service-fabric-5-5-and-sdk-2-5/

Comment: Is this documented anywhere? (I don't see a reference to it in the link.)